# Spring autowiring dependencies after each junit test

Tags: java, spring, junit

I'm having a problem whereby spring is re-creating my beans and re-auto wiring after each junit test has been run. I only want spring to do this once, on the post construct of the test class, which is what I've configured it to do.

I've also tried setting the @DirtiesContext class mode to AFTER_CLASS, but this still didn't solve the issue.

Any ideas?

Cheers.

Comment: Hi Nick, can you add the code exhibiting the problem to your question please? Thanks.

Comment: which version of JUnit and Spring you are using. And do show us your code.

Comment: Are you using @Autowired on globally declared beans?

Comment: Can you expand on your expectation of Spring creating beans on post-construct of your test class?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class:

```
@SpringJUnitConfig(classes = {ConfigClassOne.class, ConfigClassTwo.class, ConfigClassThree.class})
public abstract class ModelTest {}
```

and extend it in the test classes. Beans will not be recreated because the application contexts are already mentioned in the annotation.